# Delete Ubuntu partition on dual-boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 7 (dual-boot) in my computer but I want to keep Windows only for this computer just for gaming (so I won't be leaving Linux). My problem: I've read about resizing and deleting partitions but I'm not so sure about fixing the bootloader so that the computer starts up with Windows directly. Now, I could use some help from you guys on how to do this, as I'm a bit afraid this could brick my pc if done incorrectly.

I'm not really experienced so I'd appreciate any help, links or instructions that are as clear as possible for beginners.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You could use the Search facility in Ask Ubuntu to seek an answer to your question.  There are many responses to similar requests.  See, for example, https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: Have you actually installed both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 already?